# How to disable MAAS without uninstalling it

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, mirantis

I have a lab cluster meant for Openstack testing. I've used it for Ubuntu Openstack using Juju/MAAS, and separately, for Fuel 9.2 running on a VM on the same machine. I have been able to test Fuel and Juju separately after tearing down the stack. I can get MAAS running after shutting down the Fuel VM, but Fuel only works after I uninstall MAAS. I'm guessing it's because of the DHCP services running in Fuel and MAAS that interfere with each other.

I want to be able to disable MAAS without uninstalling it. How can I disable MAAS (without uninstalling it) to allow Fuel to work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same kind of problem, my solution was to build MaaS in a VM.  When I want MaaS I start the VM, when I don't I either save it or shut it down, depending on what I'm in the middle of.

It also makes backup real easy, just save the whole machine when you want a backup.